# How can I check the compatibility of my app against .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have a asp.net app that targets 4.5.

I'm just curious to know if there is a quick way to check which libraries I am using that are not available in asp.net core and .net core. Just to get an idea of what I might need to replace/implement at a high level if I wanted to migrate to asp.net core and .net core.

Comment: Recommendations for tools are off topic here. If you have a purpose, specific requirements and evaluation criteria see [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Guess I'm not really looking for a tool  more interested in just how I could see what libraries are being used in the project that are not compatible

Comment: Then review [ask] and then [edit] accordingly, because the title says you want a tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConnieYau.NETPortabilityAnalyzer) which is a VS extension which reports on API compatability between of your code against various .NET target frameworks (which includes versions of .NET Core and .NET Standard).

To scan your nuget dependencies (using package.config which you can upload) to see if they are supported, not support, or supported in pre-release etc.. there is [icanhasdot.net](https://icanhasdot.net)

I would suggest additionally running the analyzer tool against .NET Standard 2.0 / .NET Core 2.0 to see if it is worth waiting for, as it should be released in spring and will have many more APIs added back, it might cut your work out enough to warrant waiting.